# How is asymptotic consistency related to mean squared errors?

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, sampling, maximum-likelihood, umvue

Let $ X_1 $ , $X_2$ . . . , $X_n$ be a random sample from $ N (\mu , \sigma^2 )$.
Then the UMVUE of $\sigma^2$ is $$ \frac{n}{n-1} \frac1 n \sum_i(X_i - \bar X)^2 $$
and its MLE is $$ \frac1 n\sum_i( X_i - \bar X)^2.$$

Both the MLE and UMVUE are asymptotically consistent.  Does that also imply that both have the same mean squared errors or is there something that I am confusing regarding the concept of UMVUE and MLE?

Comment: Nope, you can't do better than MLE... if the assumptions holds, It will have smaller variance asymptotically (which is the beauty of MLE).

Answer (score 1):

No, and here is a hint on how you can check this yourself.  Recall that

$$
\frac{\sum_i^n (X_i - \bar{X})^2}{\sigma^2} \sim \chi^2_{n-1}
$$

and that the mean and variance of a $\chi^2_{n-1}$ distribution are $n - 1$ and $2(n - 1)$ respectively.  From here you should be able to get both the mean and variance of each estimator, which also tells you their mean squared errors.  You should find that the MLE actually has smaller mean squared error than the UMVUE even though it's biased.

As another exercise you might try to find the *minimum* mean squared error estimator of the form

$$
\frac{1}{c} \sum_i^n (X_i - \bar{X})^2
$$

and it isn't the MLE.